# Dynamic App Download from Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

i have an Android App on Google Play called App-1.
Basically, i want to create an In App Purchase for my user.
After the purchase of In App Purchase, i want to download app-2.

Just like the app "MY CASINO GAME" have downloaded "POKER GAME".
Can I do it dynamically without user dialogue box? I have User name/Password of Google Play.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. One think that is a lot easier is to just open app-2 from app-1 with a intent and make app-2 a paid app. Then you don't need the In App Purchase and you don  't have to do anything with username/passwords. You don't want that.